# How to make 3 or 5 column grid depending on orientation with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I want to make a grid as 3 columns for portrait and 5 columns for landscape with jquery mobile responsive grids. I tried different combinations but no success. Landscape works fine but portrait mode has 5 columns again.

Thanks for help

This is one of the codes I've tried:

```
@media all and (orientation : portrait) {
  .my-breakpoint-5.ui-grid-d .ui-block-a,
  .my-breakpoint-5.ui-grid-d .ui-block-b,
  .my-breakpoint-5.ui-grid-d .ui-block-c, 
  .my-breakpoint-5.ui-grid-d .ui-block-d,
  .my-breakpoint-5.ui-grid-d .ui-block-e { 
    width: 33%; 
  } 
}

@media all and (orientation : landscape) {
  .my-breakpoint-5 .ui-block-a,
  .my-breakpoint-5 .ui-block-b, 
  .my-breakpoint-5 .ui-block-c,
  .my-breakpoint-5 .ui-block-d,
  .my-breakpoint-5 .ui-block-e {
    width: 20%; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you considering orientation, There is a reason everyone uses width as parameter.

Comment: What is that reason? I want to use this code in a mobile application. I thought it would be better with this way, so independent from mobile device's screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the ui-grid-d class in your portrait media query:

```
<div class="my-breakpoint-5">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        a
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        b
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-c">
        c
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-d">
        d
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-e">
        e
    </div>
</div>      

@media all and (orientation : portrait) {
  .my-breakpoint-5 .ui-block-a,
  .my-breakpoint-5 .ui-block-b,
  .my-breakpoint-5 .ui-block-c, 
  .my-breakpoint-5 .ui-block-d,
  .my-breakpoint-5 .ui-block-e { 
    width: 33%; 
  } 
}

@media all and (orientation : landscape) {
  .my-breakpoint-5 .ui-block-a,
  .my-breakpoint-5 .ui-block-b, 
  .my-breakpoint-5 .ui-block-c,
  .my-breakpoint-5 .ui-block-d,
  .my-breakpoint-5 .ui-block-e {
    width: 20%; 
  }
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/y4bxb921/)**